# How to mosaic Sentinel bands with correct order in GDAL

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm new with GDAL and I'm trying to mosaic different bands from Sentinel 2 in order, what I want to get is a raster file with right order band2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8A, 11, 12. The picture below is the band list in my server.

I tried to use gdal.BuildVRT function but finally the raster I get is a disorder file, do anybody know how to set the order when I apply with the raster mosaic? Or do you have some better ways to do this?

```py
    from osgeo import gdal 
    import os
    import numpy as np
    os.chdir("/sentinel/2021/")
    print(os.listdir())
['2021_band2.tif', '2021_band8.tif', 'band.vrt', '2021_band12.tif', '2021_band11.tif', '2021_band6.tif', '2021_band7.tif', '2021_band5.tif', '2021_band4.tif', '2021_band3.tif', '2021_band8A.tif']

    tifs = os.listdir()
    tmp = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1]
    tifs = np.array(sorted(tifs))
    tifs = tifs[tmp]
    print(tifs)
['2021_band2.tif' '2021_band3.tif' '2021_band4.tif' '2021_band5.tif'
 '2021_band6.tif' '2021_band7.tif' '2021_band8.tif' '2021_band8A.tif'
 '2021_band11.tif' '2021_band12.tif']

    alltif = tifs.tolist()
    print(alltif)
['2021_band2.tif', '2021_band3.tif', '2021_band4.tif', '2021_band5.tif', '2021_band6.tif', '2021_band7.tif', '2021_band8.tif', '2021_band8A.tif', '2021_band11.tif', '2021_band12.tif']

    files_to_mosaic = alltif
    vrt = gdal.BuildVRT('2021stack.vrt', alltif)
    gdal.Translate( '/sentinel/2021/2021mosaic.tif',vrt)
<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x7f43caad6cc0> >
    
    vrt = None
```

[image]

Comment: So you write first a vrt with gdalbuildvrt from a list of tiff files? If you have a look at the vrt file, do the source files appear there in the order that you desire?

Comment: Thank you for your response here, I make them run now, I'll put all the steps here, but I'm not sure whether I'm right or not, do you know how to check band names in a raster file?

Answer (score 0):

After several times trying, I make it run. Here is the codes:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os
import numpy as np

os.chdir("the position of your folder/sentinel/2019/")
tifs = os.listdir()
tmp = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1]
tifs = np.array(sorted(tifs))
tifs = tifs[tmp]
print(tifs)

alltif = tifs.tolist()
outvrt = '/stacked.vrt'
outtif = stacked.tif'

outds = gdal.BuildVRT(outvrt, alltif, separate = True)
outds = gdal.Translate(outtif, outds)
outvrt = None
```